# Incorrect syntax near '/' when inserting data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to do an insert query and I keep getting the error:

> incorrect syntax near `'/'`

Here is what I am inserting `" /Portals/0/products/HT3-XXX.pdf "`

Why can I not insert the `'/'` ?

Do I need to convert to string? or what?

```
//Inserts 3DModel
SqlConnection sqlCon2 = new SqlConnection("...");
SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand();
sqlCmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Products].[Files] ([TypeID] ,[ProductID] ,[URL]) VALUES ('3', " + textBox15.Text + ", " + textBox4.Text + ") ";
sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlCon2;

sqlCon2.Open();
sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
sqlCon2.Close();
MessageBox.Show("3DModel for " + textBox3.Text + "' Has been Added");
```

Comment: You need to escape your input and put it in quotes. No wait - you need to use *Prepared Statements*.

Comment: What is the value of `textBox15.Text` and `textBox.Text`? What are the types of `ProductID` and `URL` columns? And use parameterized queries. This kind of string concatenations are open for _SQL Injection_ attacks.

Comment: And you need to remove sensitive data from your question.

Comment: @juergen given the history of changes, he really needs to change his password :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely, it's complaining about the URL you're using as a parameter.

```
sqlCmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Products].[Files] ([TypeID] ,[ProductID] ,[URL]) VALUES ('3', " + textBox15.Text + ", " + textBox4.Text + ") ";
sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlCon2;
```

Parameterize your query and see if it fixes the issue:

```
sqlCmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Products].[Files] ([TypeID] ,[ProductID] ,[URL]) VALUES (@TypeId, @ProductId, @Url) ";
sqlCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeId", 3);
sqlCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", textBox15.Text);
sqlCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Url", textBox4.Text);
sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlCon2;
```

Comment: @Dunleyyy333 - This is the right answer, and I'd like to add that you really, really, need to read [the OWASP article on SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).  Your original code is the classic example of how to code vulnerable sql statements.  SQL injections flaws are arguably the most frustrating attacks out there because they are common, costly, used in the most financially damaging attacks, top source of identity theft, and easily preventable.

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you! I will the OWASP as well thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Well the problem is because you are missing single quotes around the values in your concatenated query. But your query is prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use `SqlParameter`.

```
sqlCmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Products].[Files] ([TypeID] ,[ProductID] ,[URL]) VALUES ('3', @ProductID, @URL)";
sqlCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", textBox15.Text);
sqlCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@URL", textBox4.Text);
```

Consider using [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) statement with your Connection and Command object to release resources.

Comment: Why is using using better?

Comment: @Dunleyyy333, read about it on the linked article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx and http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhyTheUsingStatementIsBetterThanASharpStickInTheEyeAndASqlConnectionRefactoringExample.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to wrap the value in quotes for SQL to understand that it's a string:

```
 sqlCmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Products].[Files] ([TypeID] ,[ProductID] ,[URL]) VALUES ('3', " + textBox15.Text + ", '" + textBox4.Text + "') ";
```

However, this code is ***extremely*** vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. I'd strongly recommend using a prepared statement instead:

```
 sqlCmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Products].[Files] ([TypeID] ,[ProductID] ,[URL]) VALUES ('3', @productID, @url) ";
 sqlCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productID", textBox15.Text);
 sqlCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", textBox4.Text);
```

Comment: How would you write a prepared statement?

Comment: @Dunleyyy333 I've included an example in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You're currently using the raw content of your text fields. This is a VERY bad idea, because first of all you can't make any characters that might terminate the SQL statement. Second of all, as a result of this, anyone could write a query that drops the entire database.

Now, to answer your question, you're missing quotes around the textboxes.
Currently it could say:

('3', Textbox5ContentHere, Textbox4ContentHere)

When you want

('3', 'Textbox5ContentHere', 'Textbox4ContentHere')

@Edit: Downvoters, please explain.

Comment: First of all you don't address the sql injection...that is why this is downvoted. But don't worry , the other answers do address that....beyond that I doubt the OP can make sense of your answer...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't "drops the entire database" a pretty obvious synonym for SQL injection? Besides, he's not asking for security reviews, so strictly speaking my post does answer his question.

Comment: No it is not. Every situation where user input is capable of altering the data beyond the intended functionality is a sqlinjection. And I'm not claiming that your answer doesn't answer the question, I say it is not useful and therefor it is downvoted...

Comment: How is an answer, answering a question not useful? Correct me if I'm wrong, but when you ANSWER an ANSWER, it gives success. Basic programming, true and true is true. However true and false is indeed false. But he asked for an answer, I gave him an answer, aka. the 'if' statement DOES indeed run. If that's not useful, I don't know what is.

Comment: I can't help it that you don't like my explanation. Just for the record let me point you to [why vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and then move on, shall we?

Comment: +1, he *did* answer the question, pointing out what the OP did not see, the missing quotes.